# Is it possible to force a cloud function to create a new instance to run a request?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to run several puppeteer instances in parallel at given time intervals, but my understanding of cloud functions is that they run concurrently. Is it possible to force my cloud function to scale up whenever a request is sent? If send 3 requests I would need to create 3 instances to run my requests in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

If you send 3 requests in parallel, Cloud Functions will create 3 instances to process them in parallel (in the MaxInstance param is >= 3)

If you send 3 consecutive requests (you wait the return of one to send the next one) the same Cloud Functions instance will be use (no new instance creation, if you set global variables, they will be reused).

if you have consecutive requests, and you want to force the creation of a new instance each time (to clean up the runtime environment), you need to exit gracefully the function (add exit(0) at the end, according to your language)

Comment: I see. Is there any way to make consecutive requests and instead of them being queued up to run concurrently to have the cloud function auto scale to run the requests in parallel?

Comment: I'm not sure to have catche your question (excuse my poor english). Can you rephrase?

Comment: If I were to call the cloud function 4 times is it possible for me to create 4 instances that run in parallel? Instead of waiting for each function to finish and run concurrently one after another.

Comment: Yes, Cloud Functions instance can handle only 1 request at a time. Send 4 request in the same time will force the platform to create 4 instances and to process each request, independently, on each instance and in parallel.